# cUrl Preg Match

Tags: php, curl

I've following code:

```
$url = "HERE URL";
$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($handle);    
print_r($result);
if (preg_match('<tr><td>Listeners (current):</td><td class="streamstats">(.*) 
</td></tr>', $result, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches);
}
curl_close($handle);
```

I want to get the data from td class "streamstats", but its a whole table, with more class streamstats. What im doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide with the `$result` output

Comment: Your RegEx is wrong. It must start and end with same symbol. E.g. `/(.*).../`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

Comment: The remote website is a full website. I only need the numbers that are here:

<tr><td>Listeners (current):</td><td class="streamstats">158</td></tr>

The 158 number is changing every second, And i need that number.

Comment: [Don't use regexes for parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)